# What are the best options for a Java/jQuery polling interface?

Tags: java, jquery, web-applications

I am building an application in Java (with a jQuery frontend) that needs to talk to a third party application. it needs to update the interface every two seconds at the most.

Would it be a good idea to use comets? If so, how do they fit into the picture?

What other means/technologies can I use to make the application better?

Comment: You would need to add a little more content about what your application is going to do before people can start suggesting technologies you could use.

Comment: The application will poll stock prices from a third party app, write it to a database and then push it to the front end every second, for the polling, I have a timer that runs every second to call the third party app for data, I then have to display it to the front end using JSP or something, 

well at this point im not sure if I should use a servlet to write this out to the front end, what would you recommend? how should I go about it? 

is there any new technology that I can use instead of servlets? im absolutely clueless so any advice will be much appreciated. 

Thanks!

Comment: Is this third party app is on the same machine, network, or web accessible? For Java, servlets are pretty much the way to go, although you have your choice of containers (we use Tomcat). If you use something like DWR, you wouldn't need JSPs as the servlets would speak 'JSON' data to your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at DWR (http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)? It provides a fairly nice interface between Java and Javascript and supports Comet. I believe it even lets you target data pushes based on a number of criteria, e.g. this user or these users on this page. It can also automatically adjust pooling times (if you go this route).

I would also recommend checking out ExtJS http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html if you intend on making this more of an application then a webpage (like a blog or whatever). I am uncertain if they have any kind of Comet support built in (I don't think so), but you could easily make an adapter that kept one of their data sources up-to-date with push data. Their components, especially the grids, are top notch.